# Docker entrypoint user switch

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am creating a docker image to be used as base for other applications. The requirements are:

- application must run as non root user
- optionally, certificates must be loaded before executing the application

I created the following Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.1-alpine3.11

# Specify node/npm related envs
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn    \
    NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=1

# Change cwd for next commands
WORKDIR /home/node/code

# Set local registry
RUN echo "registry=http://192.168.100.175:4873" > /home/node/.npmrc && \
    chown -R node:node /home/node && \
    apk add --update --no-cache tzdata=2021a-r0 ca-certificates=20191127-r2 su-exec=0.2-r1

# Need root to update CA certificates in entrypoint.sh and then switch back to restricted user
USER root
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]

# Execute the service entrypoint
CMD ["sh"]
```

and `entrypoint.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

DIR_CRT="/home/node/certificates"
if [ "$(ls -A ${DIR_CRT})" ]; then
  cp -r "${DIR_CRT}/." /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
  update-ca-certificates
  echo "******* Updated CA certificates *******"
fi

exec su-exec node "$@"
```

This seems to cover the requirements but I noticed that if I open a shell inside the image it is always with `node` user even if I specify a different one from parameters:

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it -u root docker.repo.asts.com/scc-2.0/app-tg:1.6.0-beta50 whoami
node
```

Is it possible to have both the requirements and the possibility to execute a direct command with required user?

Comment: It's not good because when someone starts your image with a different entry point, they have circumvented the user switch.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -u xxx` works only if you did not use `exec` in `entrypoint` to change PID1. E.g.

```
$ docker run --rm -it node:14.15.1-alpine3.11 whoami
root
$ docker run --rm -u node -it node:14.15.1-alpine3.11 whoami
node
```

After you use `exec su-exec node "$@"` to change the user to `node`, you won't have way to use `-u xxx` again. The only solution is override the entrypoint like next, but I don't see the meaning here:

```
docker run --rm -u root --entrypoint=/bin/sh xxx
```

But, you still could use `docker exec -u root` or `docker exec -u node` to get a shell for that user in exist container.